# How to dynamically add rows to a specific UITableView section?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am a new IOS Programmer, and i am having a issue.

I have a UITableView with 2 sections, one then is static, and another one is dynamical.

In specific actions i need to add new rows for the second section in runtime..

I know how to manage a UITableView , but not a specific section

Could you help me please?

Best Regards you all

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:` method of `UITableView`

```
//Update data source with the object that you need to add
[tableDataSource addObject:newObject];

NSInteger row = //specify a row where you need to add new row
NSInteger section = //specify the section where the new row to be added, 
//section = 1 here since you need to add row at second section

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: it doesn't worked, i can add a blank row for test? or my datasource need to be ready for the new row?I have two sections, the first one is 0 or 1?

Comment: You need to set the datasource ready before inserting new row (for testing you may add a dummy object at specific index and check). If you have two sections, the first will be 0 and the second will be 1.

Comment: i am not using a data source for my sections, as i said, the idea for the first one is to be static, and for the second a dynamic, i tried to implement a data source for the dynamic one, but when i test it, both of the sections are getting filled with the data source... how can i keep the data in the first one?

Comment: Use `indexPath.section` or `section` from `UITableView` delegate methods. For eg: ` In - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` check `if (indexPath.section == 0)` for first section and `indexPath.section == 1`for second section

Comment: I get the idea, and tested it, perfect, but i have one more doubt, how can i keep the static cells in the first section? i think its something related to "reuse", the static ones i inserted using the  .storyboard... what i have to do , to return the same cell?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same method `insertRowAtIndexPath` like

```
 // Add the items into your datasource object first. Other wise you will end up with error
 // Manage the number of items in section. Then do

 NSIndexPath *indexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
 NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath1,indexPath2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

This will insert two rows to the section1. Remember before doing this you have manage your datasource object.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3** version

```
// Adding new item to your data source
dataSource.append(item)
// Appending new item to table view
yourTableView.beginUpdates()
// Creating indexpath for the new item
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: dataSource.count - 1, section: yourSection)
// Inserting new row, automatic will let iOS to use appropriate animation 
yourTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
yourTableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using scrolltoinfinite method but before that u have to import 3rd party svpulltorefresh

```
 [self.tableViewMixedFeed addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{

        CGFloat height = self.tableViewMixedFeed.frame.size.height;

        CGFloat contentYoffset = self.tableViewMixedFeed.contentOffset.y;

        CGFloat distanceFromBottom = self.tableViewMixedFeed.contentSize.height - contentYoffset;
if(distanceFromBottom<contentYoffSet)
{
 [weak insertRowAtBottom];
}
 }];

-(void)insertRowAtBottom
{
 [self.tableViewMixedFeed beginUpdates];
    [self.tableViewMixedFeed insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths1 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

     [self.tableViewMixedFeed endUpdates];
    [self.tableViewMixedFeed.infiniteScrollingView stopAnimating];
}
```

here indexpaths1 is the array of indexpaths of next cells which u want to insert in a table . 
try using loop to get the next set of arrays and store them into indexpaths1.

Comment: Value **CGFloat heigh** = self.tableViewMixedFeed.frame.size.height is not  used

Answer (score -1):

[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath1,indexPath2] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

USE THIS METHOD..

Comment: Hi asdafd, this looks like a confirmation of Anil Varghese answer, please don't add this as answer.