# how to add controls between controls in ios swift form

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, size-classes

This is the default view of my page:
[image: First view]

If the user selects gender as "Male", I need to add one more filed between Gender and Age like this:
[image: after male selection]

After Male selection, I need move all other controls to bottom, if again reset the gender box. need to hide the newly added textfield, and move up other controls back to the original place.

How to do that in IOS swift, if I add the textview between, what are the steps I need to take care in auto layout?

Comment: how you have created above controls? In TableView or in UIView?

Comment: @ChetanPrajapati, in UIVIew

Comment: Than with autolayout it's easy. See my answer

Comment: i have fond one library for it, but it is in objective-c, if you know any library like this for swift, please post here.  https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLForm#make-a-row-or-section-invisible-depending-on-other-rows-values

Comment: I want some thing like Stack Views for ios9

Answer (score 1):

If you place your textfields in tableview cell then you can add/hide the required cell by simply inserting it into the source and removing it from the source

Comment: this will take care of screen rotation and auto sizing ? I need a simple way to do this. if you have any link regarding this please post it here. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I didn’t like this kind of forms, it doesn’t looks “native”.
To implement that you can create a dynamic table and when a user tap on a cell you can insert o remove extra rows in a determinate position and even you can use one of the native animations:

```
[self.models removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[self syncModel];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Other option is to create a static table and show and hide the cells programatically

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment you are using UIView.

So,

1. When you change Gender Increase Height of UIView to (Height of textControl + gap b/w 2 controls)
2. Change the Centre of all controls after Gender Control (Only Y position) to (Height of textControl + gap b/w 2 controls) [For all controls]
3. Create / (Hide / Show) Mobile Control and set Centre property to after Gender Control (Height + Gap b/w 2 controls)

Make above task in uiview.animation so it looks pretty to change every time.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I need a right way to do it, this way  is very complicated for me, in the case of more dynamic controls on the page. what is the right way to do this dynamic form applications? the answers from here I come to know, I need to use table view for this. but I need some example for this. if possible please post some link or example.

Comment: http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/04/addingdeleting-rows-dynamically.html                         and            http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821088/how-to-dynamically-add-rows-to-a-specific-uitableview-section

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 subview in your `UIView`
one view is placed next to the gender text view and set its height '0' so the frame of first view is  (20,100,150,0) add the mobile textview and in second view add age and blabla etc.

when the gender is selected by male then change the frame of  first view so it may be  (20,100,150,50) and also change the 'Y' for second view.

Comment: hi @Rinju Jain, this is complete to update all the controls when I have more controls and dynamic controls , that dynamic control depends on the other dynamic control.

Comment: in your first view add textfields dynamically so the height is automatically increase .

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using autolayout. I have achieve same thing in one of my project.

You need to perform following

1> When you create your view using xib or by code create textfield for mobile as well.
2> give that textfiled height constraint as 0
3> hide that field 
4> create IBOutlet for that 0 height constraint of mobile textfiled.
5> On selection of Gender change this height constraint from 0 to your DEFAULT_HEIGHT of your textfiled.
6> All other textfield will be automatically adjusted

Here is my sample code

```
[self.dropOffLocationHeightConstraint setConstant:64.0];
[self.dropOffLocationView setHidden:FALSE];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```