# UITableView how to continue scrolling after reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableView in my application. When the table is scrolled almost to the end, I download more data and reload the table.

If the tableView was scrolling, at the time I call `[tableView reloadData];` scrolling stops. How can I achieve effect of not stopping the scroll meanwhile reloadData? I think I need to somehow save scrolling speed and then restore it, but how to do this?

P.D. I **really** searched this question before asking.

Comment: Which language is your code in?  Tip: do not add irrelevant tags to your question.  It makes it harder for people who are searching for answers to similar questions.  edit: I see you give an Objective-C example.  I'll go with that.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Unfortunately.

Comment: When I created this question, I added both objective-c / swift to tags. I don't really care, I can use any of them.

Comment: Did you tried to add rows using `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` instead of reloading the entire tableview?

Comment: Actually I didn't, I will try and let you know, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I thing, [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) (`insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`) is the key.

There is a use case and a nice tip described on SO: [the use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23821150/2799410) and [the tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27834515/2799410).

Answer (score 1):

Since `UITableView` is subclass of `UIScrollView`, you can use `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`
 method to determine how far it is supposed to scroll and then after table reload call `setContentOffset:animated:` with that target offset (or beginning/ending of tableview if it becomes smaller) to simulate continued scrolling
EDIT: since your `targetContentOffset` is probably going to be `CGRectZero`, you will have to recalculate it somehow using velocity from the same method

Comment: I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @Borzh Have you had any success on this one?

Comment: I hadn't fixed that.

Answer (score 1):

if i am not wrong you are looking for a function call Lazy load. I can recommend you to search SVPullToRefresh 
 [here](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh)!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I am already using it, I want table to load faster